# Assigning attributes from resx Files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resx

```
string thing = ComparaSave.Resources.Message.EmailAdrRequired;
[Required(ErrorMessage = thing)]    <---- The problem!!
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Display(Name = "Email Address")]
[StringLength(100)]
[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Throws the error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

How can I read a resource file into an attribute such as this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use :

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName= "FullNameRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResource)]
```

ErrorMessage is for string only.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Attributes can only use constant values, but resource values are not constant.

You can change ErrorMessage into ErrorMessageResourceName and not use the message text here, but the resource name of the error message string. In the attribute code you need to add code that will read the string by it's name from the resource file.

For code how to load resource strings take a look at the generated .cs file for your .resx file.